# what is the best way to send all data in listview into server?

Tags: android

how to send all data in the list view into the server can i send them all together as text or one by one and how ?

Comment: Send it in JSON format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need some more information to help you! Which server? Which interface(s) have the server?

But it recommented that you using a webservice (like REST) on your server-side and call it by HTTP(s) from your android device.

**UPDATE 1:**

With this method you can send a string-array to localhost/index.php. This send the parameters as POST.

```
public void sendArrayTOBackend(String[] listViewItems) {
    Gson gson = new Gson(); //Json-Lib form google

    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://localhost/index.php");

    try {
        // Add your data
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("data", gson.toJson(listViewItems)));
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

        // Execute HTTP Post Request
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    }
}
```

You can get on backend like this:

```
<?php

if(exists($_POST['data'])){
    $listViewItems = json_decode($_POST['data']);
    foreach ($listViewItems as $listViewItem) {
        echo $listViewItem;
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: Xampp on my computer , the question is can i send all the list view record as single record on php my admin?

Comment: You can build an array from all value of the listview and then convert it to JSON so it is a simple string which you can send to backend...!

Comment: @userr12 Please have a look at update 1 from my answer